# Create a new list of dictionaries using values from an old list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

How can I create a new list of dictionaries using only the values from an old list of dictionaries? Essentially I need the new list "new_list_of_dicts" to appear as outlined below.

```
old_list_of_dicts = [{'vid': 'transpower_036', 'name': '221_02_PB_520_REF_174050'}, {'vid': 'transpower_065', 'name': '222_05_KAL_T2E_YT_344991'}, {'vid': 'transpower_156', 'name': '226_02_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499802'}, {'vid': 'transpower_162', 'name': '226_FL01_KAL_DCE_FL_050232'}, {'vid': 'transpower_157', 'name': '226_FL02_KAL_DCE_FL_050234'}, {'name': '226_FL03_KAL_DCE_FL_050233', 'vid': 'transpower_163'}, {'vid': 'transpower_159', 'name': '226_XX_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499801'}, {'vid': 'transpower_161', 'name': '226_XX_KAL_T2E_YT_346321'}]

new_list_of_dicts = [{'transpower_036': '221_02_PB_520_REF_174050'}, {'transpower_065': '222_05_KAL_T2E_YT_344991'}, {'transpower_156': '226_02_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499802'}, {'transpower_162': '226_FL01_KAL_DCE_FL_050232'}, {'transpower_157': '226_FL02_KAL_DCE_FL_050234'}, {'226_FL03_KAL_DCE_FL_050233': 'transpower_163'}, {'transpower_159': '226_XX_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499801'}, {'transpower_161': '226_XX_KAL_T2E_YT_346321'}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If every dictionary in `old_list_of_dicts` has two values, you can do:

```py
new_list_of_dicts = [dict([d.values()]) for d in old_list_of_dicts]
print(new_list_of_dicts)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"transpower_036": "221_02_PB_520_REF_174050"},
    {"transpower_065": "222_05_KAL_T2E_YT_344991"},
    {"transpower_156": "226_02_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499802"},
    {"transpower_162": "226_FL01_KAL_DCE_FL_050232"},
    {"transpower_157": "226_FL02_KAL_DCE_FL_050234"},
    {"226_FL03_KAL_DCE_FL_050233": "transpower_163"},
    {"transpower_159": "226_XX_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499801"},
    {"transpower_161": "226_XX_KAL_T2E_YT_346321"},
]
```

---

EDIT: Previous answer that created a dict instead of a list:

```py
new_list_of_dicts = dict(d.values() for d in old_list_of_dicts)
print(new_list_of_dicts)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "transpower_036": "221_02_PB_520_REF_174050",
    "transpower_065": "222_05_KAL_T2E_YT_344991",
    "transpower_156": "226_02_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499802",
    "transpower_162": "226_FL01_KAL_DCE_FL_050232",
    "transpower_157": "226_FL02_KAL_DCE_FL_050234",
    "226_FL03_KAL_DCE_FL_050233": "transpower_163",
    "transpower_159": "226_XX_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499801",
    "transpower_161": "226_XX_KAL_T2E_YT_346321",
}
```

Comment: That creates a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: Actually your original comment that created the dictionary, not the list of dictionaries, might actually work better for me and is what I ended up utilizing in my code. Thank you!

Comment: @Rettro Thanks. I've edited the answer and put the old code back. Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use comprehension to create the new_list_of_dicts:

```
new_list_of_dicts = [{old['vid']: old['name']} for old in old_list_of_dicts]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
old_list_of_dicts = [{'vid': 'transpower_036', 'name': '221_02_PB_520_REF_174050'}, {'vid': 'transpower_065', 'name': '222_05_KAL_T2E_YT_344991'}, {'vid': 'transpower_156', 'name': '226_02_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499802'}, {'vid': 'transpower_162', 'name': '226_FL01_KAL_DCE_FL_050232'}, {'vid': 'transpower_157', 'name': '226_FL02_KAL_DCE_FL_050234'}, {'name': '226_FL03_KAL_DCE_FL_050233', 'vid': 'transpower_163'}, {'vid': 'transpower_159', 'name': '226_XX_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499801'}, {'vid': 'transpower_161', 'name': '226_XX_KAL_T2E_YT_346321'}]

new_list_of_dicts = [{d["vid"]: d["name"]} for d in old_list_of_dicts]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

new_list_of_dicts = [dict([itemgetter('vid', 'name')(d)])
                     for d in old_list_of_dicts]
```

output:

```
[{'transpower_036': '221_02_PB_520_REF_174050'},
 {'transpower_065': '222_05_KAL_T2E_YT_344991'},
 {'transpower_156': '226_02_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499802'},
 {'transpower_162': '226_FL01_KAL_DCE_FL_050232'},
 {'transpower_157': '226_FL02_KAL_DCE_FL_050234'},
 {'transpower_163': '226_FL03_KAL_DCE_FL_050233'},
 {'transpower_159': '226_XX_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499801'},
 {'transpower_161': '226_XX_KAL_T2E_YT_346321'}]
```

Alternative if you want a unique dictionary with multiple keys:

```
from operator import itemgetter
new_list_of_dicts = dict(itemgetter('vid', 'name')(d)
                         for d in old_list_of_dicts)
```

Output:

```
{'transpower_036': '221_02_PB_520_REF_174050',
 'transpower_065': '222_05_KAL_T2E_YT_344991',
 'transpower_156': '226_02_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499802',
 'transpower_162': '226_FL01_KAL_DCE_FL_050232',
 'transpower_157': '226_FL02_KAL_DCE_FL_050234',
 'transpower_163': '226_FL03_KAL_DCE_FL_050233',
 'transpower_159': '226_XX_INTL_PRSTR_ET_499801',
 'transpower_161': '226_XX_KAL_T2E_YT_346321'}
```